# Regular expressions replace

Tags: php, regex, function, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I need to remove

```
[0037][user name]
```

combination from a sentence. In the first brackets always containing numbers 
eg:

```
[0032]
```

Digit count will not exceed than 4 by any chance. In the second brackets always containing letters eg:

```
[first name]
```

anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Someone does. What if you try to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to implement regular expression syntax and try the following expression.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\[\d+]\[[a-z ]+]/i', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\d{1,4}\]\[[a-zA-Z ]+\]
```

This should do it.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/22

```
$re = "/\\[\\d{1,4}\\]\\[[a-zA-Z ]+\\]/im";
$str = "asdas asdsad [1234][asd asd] asdasd";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: You’ve spaces forgotten.

Comment: `user name`—after “user” just before “name”?